# How can subscribe to ws websocket from a nodejs server to another server?

Tags: node.js, oop, websocket

I have `microservice` in `nodejs` that must subscribe to `ws`(not socket.io) websocket written in `c#`(you can consider any language here) , please offer snippet or document for read or anything else that show how do this (not functional, with oop classes style ).

where must subscribe to messages in class and what syntax is like?

Comment: Go look at the documentation for any ws library for nodejs and you will see examples for how to use it as a client to connect to some external ws server.  The way things work here is you do your own research, you try some code and you post here with a specific coding problem when you get stuck.  You don't post here asking us to do your research for you and you shouldn't be posting about things that can be found in the documentation for any nodejs ws library.

Comment: Also, I hope you realize it is irrelevant what language the target ws server you want to connect to is written in.  You will speak the same ws protocol to connect to it, whether the target server is written in C#, Java, Javascript, Python or something else.

Comment: first of all i wrote that if you know document give me because i didn't find one , all of them are in express env , functional , server for application , and provider server, you didn't even read question. it's not express , it's oop , it's microservice and it's client not server.

Comment: plus here is place to ask question , my ide inform me of typo , every question is not about scripts. sorry if you had not answer for it.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking for beyond what is already documented [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket#client-example) and [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws#usage-examples) in two of the more popular websocket libraries for nodejs. If you're looking for some other programming style, then be very specific with code examples in your question about what type of style you are looking for. I'd be happy to help if I understood the question.  And yes, I have read the question multiple times.  It doesn't usually help you get answers faster when you insult the people trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried millions way but you have to implement it with raw 'ws' when listen on others server in nestjs.

```
// -------------------- Packages ------------------

import { InjectQueue } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { Inject, Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as WebSocket from 'ws';

// ------------------------------------------------

@Injectable()
export class SocketService {
  // -------------------- LGGER --------------------------

  private logger = new Logger(SocketService.name);

  // ------------------- Filelds and Props ---------------

  private readonly routeForSocket = 'wss://yourSenderAddressMaybeIsC#orJAVA';
  private socketRLC: WebSocket;

  // ------------------- Ctor ---------------

  constructor() {
    this.onRLCSocketClose = this.onRLCSocketClose.bind(this);
    this.onRLCSocketError = this.onRLCSocketError.bind(this);
    this.onRLCSocketOpen = this.onRLCSocketOpen.bind(this);
    this.onRLCSocketMessage = this.onRLCSocketMessage.bind(this);
  }

  // =================== INIT SOCKET  ========================

  public initSocketRLC(rlcToken: string) {
    this.socketRLC = new WebSocket(this.routeForSocket,'token-if-need');
    this.socketRLC.onopen = this.onRLCSocketOpen;
    this.socketRLC.onerror = this.onRLCSocketError;
    this.socketRLC.onmessage = this.onRLCSocketMessage;
    this.socketRLC.onclose = this.onRLCSocketClose;
  }

  // SOCKET Listen On Open --------------------------------------------

  public async onRLCSocketOpen(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    if (msg.type === 'open') {
      console.log('hellow');
    }
  }

  // SOCKET Listen MESSAGE HANDLER ------------------------------------------

  public async onRLCSocketMessage(msg: any) {
    const msgArr = msg.data.split(',');
    // console.log(msgArr, 'i am messagesssssssssssssssssssssss');
   
  }

  // SOCKET Listen ERROR HANDLER --------------------------------------------

  public onRLCSocketError(error: any)
    console.log(error, 'i am error');
  }

  // SOCKET Listen CLOSE HANDLER --------------------------------------------

  public async onRLCSocketClose(cmp: any) {
    console.log(cmp);
  }

  // SOCKET CLOSE BY FORCE --------------------------------------------------

  public async closeRLC(): Promise<any> {
    this.socketRLC.close();
  }
}
```